# Javafx combobox with checkbox

Tags: javafx, checkbox, combobox

I want to know how to change the selectionmodel of javafxml combobox so that it can allow multiple seletion. I try to create a JavaFX ComboBox with CheckBoxes in the dropdown menu. My code:

```
public void alLStatus() throws SQLException {

    allStatus.clear();
    cb_statuItem.getItems().clear();
    DbManager test = new DbManager();
    String sql = "SELECT allStatus FROM Items ;";

    Statement stmt = test.connect().createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    while (rs.next()) {
        Items a = new Items();
        a.setStatusItems(rs.getString("statusItems"));
        allStatus.add(a);
    }
    test.disconnect();
    cb_statuItem.setItems(allStatus);

    cb_statuItem.setConverter(new StringConverter<Items>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(Items object) {

            // //System.out.print("converting object: ");
            if (object == null) {
                // //System.out.println("null");
                return "[none]";
            }
            // //System.out.println(object.toString());
            return object.getStatusItems();
        }

        @Override
        public Items fromString(String string) {
            throw new RuntimeException("not required for non editable ComboBox");
        }
    });


    cb_statuItem.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Items>, ListCell<Items>>() {
            @Override
            public ListCell<Items> call(ListView<Items> param) {
                return new ListCell<Items>() {
                    private CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                    private BooleanProperty booleanProperty;

                    {
                        cb.setOnAction(e->getListView().getSelectionModel().select(getItem()));
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Items item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (!empty) {


                                booleanProperty = item.selectedProperty();
                                cb.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(booleanProperty); 
                                setGraphic(cb);
                                setText(item.getStatusItems() + "");

                        } else {
                            setGraphic(null);
                            setText(null);
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });



}
```

ComboBox show text like status of Items but don't allow to click on checkbox, it's automatically close. 
I want to check more items from comboBox and get them in list. BooleanProperty is always return false.

Any contribution will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: You did notice that you may create bindings between items, since multiple items could be added to the same cell one after the other, especially if there are enough items for a scrollbar to appear? Also why implement [things that are already available](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/CheckComboBox.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [controlsfx](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/), it's a library for JavaFX components, and has a component called 
CheckComboBox, which seems to be exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example sample code for the problem which can give some new idea. Just an example how Checkbox can be added to Combobox.

```
import org.controlsfx.control.CheckComboBox;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class ComboUI extends BaseUI implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    private CheckComboBox selector;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> subAcc;

    private List<String> filelist;

    //These two functions: print_valuefromcheckcombobox & showDropdownValue added to 
    //print and add elements in check-combobox list.
    public void print_valuefromcheckcombobox() {

        ObservableList list = selector.getCheckModel().getCheckedItems();
        this.filelist= list;
        this.filelist.forEach(name -> {
             System.out.println(name);
        }) 
    }

    public void showDropdownValue () {
        //Show Dropdown value: Adding elements in Comboobox
        List<String> fileNameList = new ArrayList<>();
        fileNameList.add("First");
        fileNameList.add("Second");

        selector.getItems().setAll(fileNameList);
}
```

In fxml file, Add where you want to put your combobox. (Just an example..)

```
<?import org.controlsfx.control.CheckComboBox?>

<ComboBox fx:id="subAcc" layoutX="136.0" layoutY="48.0" onAction="#showDropdownValue" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Select Sub-Account" />    
<CheckComboBox fx:id="selector" layoutX="157.0" layoutY="25.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="220.0" />
```

For Maven Project, Add following dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
        <version>8.40.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>controlsfx-samples</artifactId>
        <version>8.40.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>fxsampler</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
```